# jquery query string creation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my php page i use jquery code to make it dynamic and i have problem in creating query string and my small sample of code is.

```
$.listSemester = function(selStreamId) {
    var obj = { year: $( "#batches option:selected" ).text() };
    $.ajax({
        url:"searchStream.php?" + $.param(obj),
        data:{
            streamId:selStreamId,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#sem').html(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

i want to pass variable **year** in query string and it's value coming from another jquery code. my full jquery code is.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sidebar-menu .system').addClass('active');
    $('.sidebar-menu .system .student').addClass('active');
    $(".sidebar-menu .system").tree();
    $('#streams').change(function() {
        $('#branches').html("<option value=''>-- Select --</option>");
        $('#batches').html("<option value=''>-- Select --</option>");
        $('.divAfter').hide();
        $('.divBefore').show();
        $('.semesterAfter').hide();
        $('.semesterBefore').show();
        $('.btnAdd').hide();
        $('.btnExcel').hide();
        $('.studList').hide();
        if($(this).val() == '') {
        }
        else {
            $.when($.streamSelection($(this).val())).then($.listSemester($(this).val()));
        }
    });
    $('#branches').change(function() {
        $('#batches').html("<option value=''>-- Select --</option>");
        $('.divAfter').hide();
        $('.divBefore').show();
        $('.semesterAfter').hide();
        $('.semesterBefore').show();
        $('.btnAdd').hide();
        $('.btnExcel').hide();
        $('.studList').hide();
        if($(this).val() == '') {
        }
        else {
            $.branchSelection($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $('#batches').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $('.divAfter').hide();
            $('.divBefore').show();
            $('.semesterAfter').hide();
            $('.semesterBefore').show();
            $('.btnAdd').hide();
            $('.btnExcel').hide();
            $('.studList').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('.divBefore').hide();
            $('#division').val('');
            $('.divAfter').show();
        }
    });
    $('#division').change(function() {
        $('.studList').hide();
        $('.semesterAfter').hide();
        $('.semesterBefore').show();
        $('.btnAdd').hide();
        $('.btnExcel').hide();
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $('.semesterBefore').hide();
            $('#sem').val('');
            $('.semesterAfter').show();
        }
    });
    $('#sem').change(function() {
        $('.btnAdd').hide();
        $('.btnExcel').hide();
        $('.studList').hide();
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $.when($('.btnAdd').attr('href', 'add.php?streamId='+$('#streams').val()+'&branchId='+$('#branches').val()+'&batchId='+$('#batches').val()+'&divisionId='+$('#division').val()+'&semId='+$('#sem').val()))
            .then($('.btnExcel').attr('href', 'studExcel.php?streamId='+$('#streams').val()+'&branchId='+$('#branches').val()+'&batchId='+$('#batches').val()+'&divisionId='+$('#division').val()+'&semId='+$('#sem').val()))
            .then($('.btnAdd').show())
            .then($.studentList($('#streams').val(),$('#branches').val(),$('#batches').val(),$('#division').val(),$('#sem').val()));
        }
    });
});
$.streamSelection = function(selStreamId) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"searchBranch.php",
        data:{
            streamId:selStreamId
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#branches').html(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
$.branchSelection = function(selBranchId) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"searchBatch.php",
        data:{
            branchId:selBranchId,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#batches').html(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
$.listSemester = function(selStreamId) {
    var obj = { year: $( "#batches option:selected" ).text() };
    $.ajax({
        url:"searchStream.php?" + $.param(obj),
        data:{
            streamId:selStreamId,
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#sem').html(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
$.studentList = function(streamId,branchId,batchId,divisionId,semId) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"searchStudent.php",
        data:{
            selStreamId     :   streamId,
            selBranchId     :   branchId,
            selBatchId      :   batchId,
            selDivisionId   :   divisionId,
            selSemId        :   semId
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('.studList').html(data);
            $('.studList').show();
            if(data.length > 0)
                $('.btnExcel').show();
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

now it's pass noting in query string.

Comment: What is your `$.param(obj)` returning??

Comment: alert or console.log the value of obj and see whether you are getting the right value in the variable

Comment: place a keyword `debugger;` above your ajax call line ie: after your ` var obj = { year: $( "#batches option:selected" ).text() };` line of code. And when you are in the page open browser console and the run whatever that will trigger this ajax post. your debugger will be hit and just type this int console `$.param(obj)` and it will give you the result.

Comment: No `option` element has been selected when `$.listSemester` is called ?

Comment: yes no option are selected.

Comment: That is why `$.param()` returns `"year="` when selector `$( "#batches option:selected" ).text()` is used to set value of `"year"` property of `obj`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `this` in callback functions, it's not saved in closures. Create a local variable.

Also, the argument to `.then()` must be a function, otherwise you'll call `$.listSemester` immediately, not when the AJAX call returns.

```
$('#streams').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('#branches').html("<option value=''>-- Select --</option>");
    $('#batches').html("<option value=''>-- Select --</option>");
    $('.divAfter').hide();
    $('.divBefore').show();
    $('.semesterAfter').hide();
    $('.semesterBefore').show();
    $('.btnAdd').hide();
    $('.btnExcel').hide();
    $('.studList').hide();
    if($this.val() == '') {
    }
    else {
        $.when($.streamSelection($this.val())).then(function() {
            $.listSemester($this.val());
        });
    }
});
```

And since the argument to `$.when()` needs to be a `Deferred`, you need to return a value from `$.streamSelection()`.

```
$.streamSelection = function(selStreamId) {
    return $.ajax({
        url:"searchBranch.php",
        data:{
            streamId:selStreamId
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#branches').html(data);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Or, since you're just interested in the value, you could just save that in a variable.

```
$('#streams').change(function() {
    var $thisVal = $(this).val();
    $('#branches').html("<option value=''>-- Select --</option>");
    $('#batches').html("<option value=''>-- Select --</option>");
    $('.divAfter').hide();
    $('.divBefore').show();
    $('.semesterAfter').hide();
    $('.semesterBefore').show();
    $('.btnAdd').hide();
    $('.btnExcel').hide();
    $('.studList').hide();
    if($thisVal == '') {
    }
    else {
        $.when($.streamSelection($thisVal)).then(function() {
            $.listSemester($this.val());
        });
    }
});
```

You need to make similar fixes to other functions.

Comment: @guest271314 Good catch, I've shown how to fix that problem.